# Zugfered Schematron validation of the submitted XRechnung failed

Tags: c#, xml, xsd-validation, schematron, zugferd

I am trying to convert a German invoice PDF to Zugfered Xrechnung format using C# ZUGFeRD-csharp (s2industries) library.

`ZUGFeRDVersion.Version21, s2industries.ZUGFeRD.Profile.XRechnung`

I can get XRechnung XML too, But if validate that xml using Xrechnung Validator getting below exception

`Schematron validation of the submitted XRechnung failed`. Here I have attach my XML, kindly help me what i need to add in it to resolve schematron issue. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice xmlns:a="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100" xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100">
  <rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
    <ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
      <ram:ID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:standard:xrechnung_2.0</ram:ID>
    </ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
  <rsm:ExchangedDocument>
    <ram:ID>1111111</ram:ID>
    <ram:TypeCode>111</ram:TypeCode>
    <ram:IssueDateTime>
      <udt:DateTimeString format="102">20221219</udt:DateTimeString>
    </ram:IssueDateTime>
    <ram:IncludedNote>
      <ram:Content>dummy content
</ram:Content>
      <ram:SubjectCode>REG</ram:SubjectCode>
    </ram:IncludedNote>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocument>
  <rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction>
    <ram:IncludedSupplyChainTradeLineItem>
      <ram:AssociatedDocumentLineDocument>
        <ram:LineID>1</ram:LineID>
      </ram:AssociatedDocumentLineDocument>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradeProduct>
        <ram:Name> </ram:Name>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradeProduct>
      <ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement>
        <ram:GrossPriceProductTradePrice>
          <ram:ChargeAmount>2840.00</ram:ChargeAmount>
        </ram:GrossPriceProductTradePrice>
        <ram:NetPriceProductTradePrice>
          <ram:ChargeAmount>2840.0000</ram:ChargeAmount>
        </ram:NetPriceProductTradePrice>
      </ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement>
      <ram:SpecifiedLineTradeDelivery>
        <ram:BilledQuantity unitCode="H87">0.00</ram:BilledQuantity>
      </ram:SpecifiedLineTradeDelivery>
      <ram:SpecifiedLineTradeSettlement>
        <ram:ApplicableTradeTax>
          <ram:TypeCode>VAT</ram:TypeCode>
          <ram:ExemptionReason>Normalsatz</ram:ExemptionReason>
          <ram:CategoryCode>S</ram:CategoryCode>
          <ram:RateApplicablePercent>19.00</ram:RateApplicablePercent>
        </ram:ApplicableTradeTax>
        <ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementLineMonetarySummation>
          <ram:LineTotalAmount>0.00</ram:LineTotalAmount>
        </ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementLineMonetarySummation>
      </ram:SpecifiedLineTradeSettlement>
    </ram:IncludedSupplyChainTradeLineItem>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement>
      <ram:BuyerReference>992-03005-81</ram:BuyerReference>
      <ram:SellerTradeParty>
        <ram:Name>dummy name
</ram:Name>
        <ram:DefinedTradeContact>
          <ram:PersonName>dummy person
</ram:PersonName>
        </ram:DefinedTradeContact>
        <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
          <ram:PostcodeCode />
          <ram:LineOne />
          <ram:CityName />
          <ram:CountryID>DE</ram:CountryID>
        </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
      </ram:SellerTradeParty>
      <ram:BuyerTradeParty>
        <ram:Name>
dummy DLR

</ram:Name>
        <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
          <ram:PostcodeCode />
          <ram:LineOne />
          <ram:CityName />
          <ram:CountryID>DE</ram:CountryID>
        </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
      </ram:BuyerTradeParty>
    </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery>
      <ram:ActualDeliverySupplyChainEvent>
        <ram:OccurrenceDateTime>
          <udt:DateTimeString format="102">20221219</udt:DateTimeString>
        </ram:OccurrenceDateTime>
      </ram:ActualDeliverySupplyChainEvent>
    </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement>
      <ram:InvoiceCurrencyCode>EUR</ram:InvoiceCurrencyCode>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementPaymentMeans>
        <ram:TypeCode>58</ram:TypeCode>
        <ram:Information>dummy info </ram:Information>
        <ram:PayeePartyCreditorFinancialAccount>
          <ram:IBANID>dummy banid</ram:IBANID>
        </ram:PayeePartyCreditorFinancialAccount>
        <ram:PayeeSpecifiedCreditorFinancialInstitution>
          <ram:BICID>dummy BIC</ram:BICID>
        </ram:PayeeSpecifiedCreditorFinancialInstitution>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementPaymentMeans>
      <ram:ApplicableTradeTax>
        <ram:CalculatedAmount>544.54</ram:CalculatedAmount>
        <ram:TypeCode>VAT</ram:TypeCode>
        <ram:BasisAmount>2866.00</ram:BasisAmount>
        <ram:CategoryCode>S</ram:CategoryCode>
        <ram:RateApplicablePercent>19.00</ram:RateApplicablePercent>
      </ram:ApplicableTradeTax>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradePaymentTerms>
        <ram:Description>Terms of payment</ram:Description>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradePaymentTerms>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
        <ram:LineTotalAmount>2866.00</ram:LineTotalAmount>
        <ram:ChargeTotalAmount>0.00</ram:ChargeTotalAmount>
        <ram:AllowanceTotalAmount>0.00</ram:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>2866.00</ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>
        <ram:TaxTotalAmount currencyID="EUR">544.54</ram:TaxTotalAmount>
        <ram:GrandTotalAmount>3410.54</ram:GrandTotalAmount>
        <ram:TotalPrepaidAmount>0.00</ram:TotalPrepaidAmount>
        <ram:DuePayableAmount>3410.54</ram:DuePayableAmount>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
    </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement>
  </rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction>
</rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice>
```

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like a really specific issue with a really specific vendor software, and it should not need saying that your best path to resolution may be to contact the company's support team.

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of some issues, typecode has to be 380=invoice,
Item name, post code and city name (neither in sender nor recipient) may be empty, sellertradeparty needs a UStID SpecifiedTaxRegistration.

Now up for some XRechnug specialities : the seller contact person needs a  TelephoneUniversalCommunication and EmailURIUniversalCommunication and the ibanid has to be a correct IBAN. If you put 1.00  instead of 0.00 on billedquantity you get a linetotalamount 2840 (also in  SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation/linetotalamount and ApplicableTradeTax->BasisAmount ).
ApplicableTradeTax->CalculatedAmount and TaxTotalAmount is then 539.60,
grandtotal and due payable sums up to 3379.60. In total the valid invoice will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice xmlns:a="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100" xmlns:qdt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:QualifiedDataType:100" xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100">
  <rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
    <ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
      <ram:ID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:standard:xrechnung_2.0</ram:ID>
    </ram:GuidelineSpecifiedDocumentContextParameter>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocumentContext>
  <rsm:ExchangedDocument>
    <ram:ID>1111111</ram:ID>
    <ram:TypeCode>380</ram:TypeCode>
    <ram:IssueDateTime>
      <udt:DateTimeString format="102">20221219</udt:DateTimeString>
    </ram:IssueDateTime>
    <ram:IncludedNote>
      <ram:Content>dummy content
</ram:Content>
      <ram:SubjectCode>REG</ram:SubjectCode>
    </ram:IncludedNote>
  </rsm:ExchangedDocument>
  <rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction>
    <ram:IncludedSupplyChainTradeLineItem>
      <ram:AssociatedDocumentLineDocument>
        <ram:LineID>1</ram:LineID>
      </ram:AssociatedDocumentLineDocument>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradeProduct>
        <ram:Name>AName </ram:Name>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradeProduct>
      <ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement>
        <ram:GrossPriceProductTradePrice>
          <ram:ChargeAmount>2840.00</ram:ChargeAmount>
        </ram:GrossPriceProductTradePrice>
        <ram:NetPriceProductTradePrice>
          <ram:ChargeAmount>2840.0000</ram:ChargeAmount>
        </ram:NetPriceProductTradePrice>
      </ram:SpecifiedLineTradeAgreement>
      <ram:SpecifiedLineTradeDelivery>
        <ram:BilledQuantity unitCode="H87">0.00</ram:BilledQuantity>
      </ram:SpecifiedLineTradeDelivery>
      <ram:SpecifiedLineTradeSettlement>
        <ram:ApplicableTradeTax>
          <ram:TypeCode>VAT</ram:TypeCode>
          <ram:ExemptionReason>Normalsatz</ram:ExemptionReason>
          <ram:CategoryCode>S</ram:CategoryCode>
          <ram:RateApplicablePercent>19.00</ram:RateApplicablePercent>
        </ram:ApplicableTradeTax>
        <ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementLineMonetarySummation>
          <ram:LineTotalAmount>2840.00</ram:LineTotalAmount>
        </ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementLineMonetarySummation>
      </ram:SpecifiedLineTradeSettlement>
    </ram:IncludedSupplyChainTradeLineItem>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement>
      <ram:BuyerReference>992-03005-81</ram:BuyerReference>
      <ram:SellerTradeParty>
        <ram:Name>dummy name
</ram:Name>
        <ram:DefinedTradeContact>
          <ram:PersonName>dummy person</ram:PersonName>
            <ram:TelephoneUniversalCommunication>
                <ram:CompleteNumber>+49891234567</ram:CompleteNumber>
            </ram:TelephoneUniversalCommunication>
            <ram:EmailURIUniversalCommunication>
                <ram:URIID>Max@Mustermann.de</ram:URIID>
            </ram:EmailURIUniversalCommunication>


        </ram:DefinedTradeContact> 
        <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
          <ram:PostcodeCode>12345</ram:PostcodeCode>
          <ram:LineOne />
          <ram:CityName>test</ram:CityName>
          <ram:CountryID>DE</ram:CountryID>
        </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
        <ram:SpecifiedTaxRegistration>
<ram:ID schemeID="VA">DE136695976</ram:ID>
</ram:SpecifiedTaxRegistration>
      </ram:SellerTradeParty>
      <ram:BuyerTradeParty>
        <ram:Name>
dummy DLR

</ram:Name>
        <ram:PostalTradeAddress>
          <ram:PostcodeCode>55555</ram:PostcodeCode>
          <ram:LineOne />
          <ram:CityName>TStadt</ram:CityName>
          <ram:CountryID>DE</ram:CountryID>
        </ram:PostalTradeAddress>
      </ram:BuyerTradeParty>
    </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery>
      <ram:ActualDeliverySupplyChainEvent>
        <ram:OccurrenceDateTime>
          <udt:DateTimeString format="102">20221219</udt:DateTimeString>
        </ram:OccurrenceDateTime>
      </ram:ActualDeliverySupplyChainEvent>
    </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeDelivery>
    <ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement>
      <ram:InvoiceCurrencyCode>EUR</ram:InvoiceCurrencyCode>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementPaymentMeans>
        <ram:TypeCode>58</ram:TypeCode>
        <ram:Information>dummy info </ram:Information>
        <ram:PayeePartyCreditorFinancialAccount>
          <ram:IBANID>DE02120300000000202051</ram:IBANID>
        </ram:PayeePartyCreditorFinancialAccount>
        <ram:PayeeSpecifiedCreditorFinancialInstitution>
          <ram:BICID>dummy BIC</ram:BICID>
        </ram:PayeeSpecifiedCreditorFinancialInstitution>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementPaymentMeans>
      <ram:ApplicableTradeTax>
        <ram:CalculatedAmount>539.60</ram:CalculatedAmount>
        <ram:TypeCode>VAT</ram:TypeCode>
        <ram:BasisAmount>2840.00</ram:BasisAmount>
        <ram:CategoryCode>S</ram:CategoryCode>
        <ram:RateApplicablePercent>19.00</ram:RateApplicablePercent>
      </ram:ApplicableTradeTax>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradePaymentTerms>
        <ram:Description>Terms of payment</ram:Description>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradePaymentTerms>
      <ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
        <ram:LineTotalAmount>2840.00</ram:LineTotalAmount>
        <ram:ChargeTotalAmount>0.00</ram:ChargeTotalAmount>
        <ram:AllowanceTotalAmount>0.00</ram:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>2840.00</ram:TaxBasisTotalAmount>
        <ram:TaxTotalAmount currencyID="EUR">539.60</ram:TaxTotalAmount>
        <ram:GrandTotalAmount>3379.60</ram:GrandTotalAmount>
        <ram:TotalPrepaidAmount>0.00</ram:TotalPrepaidAmount>
        <ram:DuePayableAmount>3379.60</ram:DuePayableAmount>
      </ram:SpecifiedTradeSettlementHeaderMonetarySummation>
    </ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeSettlement>
  </rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction>
</rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice>
```